# Type Inference for Union Types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, oop, typing

Say I have three base classes or types as below:

```
type A = { one: number };
type B = { one: number, two: string };
type C = { one: number, two: string, three: boolean };
```

Now I would like to create a typed array that holds a number any of instances of these types, so I declare a *Union Type* which will be used for the array:

```
type X = A | B | C;
```

Defining the array elements here and constructing the array:

```
const a: A = { one: 1 };
const b: B = { one: 1, two: '2' };
const c: C = { one: 1, two: '2', three: true };

let list: X[] = [a, b, c];
```

Now if I try to access the `two` property of the second or third element in this array, I get the following error:

```
const z: X = list[2];
z.two;                // yields this error
error TS2339: Property 'two' does not exist on type 'X'. Property 'two' does not exist on type 'A'.
```

I have tried changing the type of `A` -- and others in fact, from `const a: A` to `const a: X`, but I still get the same error.

If I cast `z: X` to `z: B` instead; I still get a very similar error again:

```
const z: B = list[2];
z.two;                // yields this error
Type 'X' is not assignable to type 'B'. Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'. Property 'two' is missing in type 'A'.
```

To me it does seem that TypeScript's type inference mechanism is somehow overrides my explicit typing and basically instead of creating `list: X[]` it has created a down-casted version which is `list: A[]`.

I have also tried using `class` and `interface` definition to see if it makes a difference -- even though I was sure it wouldn't due to [TypeScript's Structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) [Type System](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#structural), and as expected nothing changed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here or any suggestions for a better approach?

**Answer**

It turned-out change `const z: B = list[2]` to `const z = <B>list[2]` does the proper casting that I had the intention of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not overriding your explicit typing... it's *obeying* your explicit typing by treating `list` as an array of elements of type `X`.  An `X` can be either an `A`, a `B`, or a `C`.  If I hand you a value of type `X`, it is safe to read the `one` property, because that definitely exists.  But it is *unsafe* to try to read the `two` property, because the `X` might be an `A`, and `A` is not known to have a `two`.  So you get a useful error:

```
z.two; // error!
// Property 'two' does not exist on type 'X'. Property 'two' does not exist on type 'A'.
```

---

So, what are your options?  One is to just tell the compiler that you know better than it does, by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) as in the other answer:

```
(z as B).two; // okay now
```

This suppresses the compiler error, but that really isn't a great solution because it is partially disabling type checking when it doesn't need to.  The following also will not be an error, but it would give you problems at runtime:

```
(list[0] as B).two.length;  // no compile error
// at runtime: TypeError: list[0].two is undefined
```

Usually, type assertions should be a last resort of dealing with compiler errors, to be used only where you cannot find a reasonable way to convince the compiler that what you are doing is safe, and you are positive that it is safe and will remain safe even in the face of possible code changes (e.g., you change `list` to `[b,c,a]` in the future).

---

A better solution is to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-type-assertions) to convince the compiler that what you are doing is safe.  This has a run-time impact, in that you are running more code, but the code you are running is more future-proof if you change `list` somewhere down the line.  Here's a way to do it:

```
const z = list[2]; // z is inferred as A | B | C
if ('two' in z) {
  // z is now narrowed to B | C
  z.two; // okay
}
```

So you are guarding the read of `z.two` by using `in` to check the presence of the `two` property before using it.  This is now safe.  If you are thinking "why should I go through this trouble when I know that `z` will be of type `B` (actually `C`, ha ha, `list[2]` is the *third* element)", then read on:

---

If you are sure that `list` will always be a three-element array of types `A`, `B`, and `C`, in that order, then you can tell the compiler this and get the behavior you expect at compile time without any runtime guarding.   You are looking for [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
const list: [A, B, C] = [a, b, c];

const z = list[2];
z.two; // okay
z.three; // okay
```

You've told the compiler that `list` is a three-element *tuple* of type `[A, B, C]`.  Now there are no errors (and it can see that `z` is a `C`).  This is safe, with zero run-time impact.  It also prevents you from messing with `list`:

```
list[1] = a; // error!  A is not assignable to B
```

since you've told it `list[1]` is always a `B`, then you must assign something compatible with `B` to it:

```
list[1] = c; // okay, C is assignable to B
```

---

So there are three options for you: assertions, type guards, and tuples, with tuples being the one I'd recommend for this situation.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Very useful answer indeed. The thing is that the example code here is overly simplified. But I do agree with all of your points. In reality, I do filter the array elements properly before using them and accessing the properties also happens afterwards were I'm sure the element has the property -- very similar to the Type Guards. I will still try to have a look again and make sure I'm not making any bad design decisions in my real code. Again, very useful and totally agree with all of your suggestions.

Comment: Are you using `Array.prototype.filter()` to filter?  If so, there is an [overload](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.1.3/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1250) you can use to behave as a type guard, but it needs some [explicit annotation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) to work.  If you have a more targeted question you want to open, you might get a more appropriate answer.  Good luck!

Comment: Great, thanks! That's very interesting. It's been very useful so far and hopefully will be sufficient. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a type assertion eg.

```
const z = <B>list[2]; // omitting the .two because that would never be assignable to B
```

?

Comment: Ah sorry I never actually tried getting the `.two` property. That was a mistake transferring my code to here.

Comment: Actually, changing from `const z: B = list[2]` to `const z = <B>list[2]` did solve the problem! Will be nice if you edit your answer to reflect this as I have already accepted your answer as the correct one!

Comment: @Mahdi Note that this is not the _good_ way of solving things. A cast will discard whatever guarantees the type system was providing, allowing you to say that whatever you are retrieving from the list is that specific type `B`. This is not always the case, because of the union type.

Comment: @E_net4 It's a very good point, thanks for the heads-up, but in my actual code I do actually filter items when returning them. The problem really was the TypeScript's type system not realising that. But I totally see your point and fully agree.